# Changes in files cannot be detected

Tags: filesystem, git, btrfs

It has been a long time, that on my laptop, git or megasync cannot detect the change on files. They see new files, but not changed files. The filesystem is mounted as:
`/dev/mapper/vgroot-lvroot on / type btrfs (rw,relatime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=523,subvol=/@root)`

```
/tmp$ mkdir test; cd test
/tmp/test$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/test/.git/
/tmp/test$ touch a
/tmp/test$ git stage a
/tmp/test$ git commit -a -m 'a'
[master (root-commit) ea2464b] a
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a
/tmp/test$ stat a
  File: 'a'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 17h/23d Inode: 12931371    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (SOMETHING)   Gid: (SOMETHING)
Access: 2016-11-07 19:55:44.945089596 +0800
Modify: 2016-11-07 19:55:44.945089596 +0800
Change: 2016-11-07 19:55:44.945089596 +0800
 Birth: -
/tmp/test$ vim a
/tmp/test$ stat a
  File: 'a'
  Size: 4               Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 17h/23d Inode: 12931371    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (SOMETHING)   Gid: (SOMETHING)
Access: 2016-11-07 19:56:04.804211299 +0800
Modify: 2016-11-07 19:56:06.980224918 +0800
Change: 2016-11-07 19:56:06.985224949 +0800
 Birth: -
/tmp/test$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```